# Encoding in XML in android

Tags: android, character-encoding

I read XML with Russian words:

```
xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            file = new File(getFilesDir()+"/shops.xml");
            fis = null;
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            eventType = 0;
            eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            do 
            {
                 if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) 
                 {
                     String strName = xpp.getName();
                     if (strName.equals("Shop")) 
                     {
                         String nameSh = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                         Shops.add(nameSh);
                     }
                 }
                 eventType = xpp.next();
             }
            while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT);
```

File in UTF - 
But when I Show string Array in dialog, I cant read the words.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
          adb.setTitle(R.string.items);
          String[] Shopsx=new String[Shops.size()];
          for(int k=0;k<Shops.size();k++)
          {
              Shopsx[k]=Shops.get(k);
          }
          adb.setSingleChoiceItems(Shopsx, -1, myClickListener);
          adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, myClickListener);
          return adb .create();
      }
```

My Xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Utf-8' ?>
<Shops>
 <Shop name="Первый" ></Shop>
 <Shop name="Второй"></Shop>
 <Shop name="Третий"></Shop>
</Shops>
```

I expect to see list with 3 checkbox (Первый, Второй, Третий), but see list with black rhombus. If use in xml english words, view is ok.
Could you help to find, what is wrong.

Comment: Can you show US the string array in dialog? Can you further tell us what you expect to see?

Comment: I edited question, see it please.

Comment: *Concretely*, if your input is <foo>bar</foo>, what do you see? What do you expect to see? Likewise, if your input is <foo>[cyrillic]bar</foo>, what do you see and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

I think your encoding should be `utf-8` and not `Utf-8`. Try that and see how you get on.

Comment: That indicates your encoding is something other than utf-8. While you should fix this, as a diagnosis and duct tape, try encoding="iso-8859-5". According to http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CharEncoding.html, that's cyrillic, which I believe is what Russian is written using.

Answer (score 0):

My OS is Mac OS x and by default I edit file in TextEdit. I setup Sublime Text 2 and save shop.xml as utf-8, and then push it on DDMS